# How to run R through PHP with exec?

Tags: php, r, exec

I am going to ask something, that I know that it has been asked already some times. But since, all of the past posts are quite old and none of them answer my problem..I try again.
I am completely new in R language and relative new in php. 
What I want to do is to use the exec() function from php in order to execute a R script.
Most of the people here will start talking about rapache, rserve and I don't know what else..but since I am not familiar with all these technologies, I prefer just using exec.

The code I will show here is working just fine when I run it with Rscript from the terminal.
       # R script
      png("temp.png")
      plot(5,5)
      dev.off()

But when I try to run it either with Rscript or with R CMD BATCH from PHP, like this:

```
       echo exec("Rscript my_rscript.R"); //OR
       //echo exec("R CMD BATCH my_rscript.R");
```

I get nothing back.

I have checked if exec() function is available and if it works. Everything is ok with this.
I read also, that I might have to change the permissions of the webserver...but I don't know how to do this in mamp.

I hope I am clear with my problem and someone can help.

Thanks
Dimitris

Comment: Does this work in a command prompt window? If not either it's not installed correctly or the executable is not in the system path.

Comment: @cryptic: When I run the R script in the command window (Rscript my_rscript.R )..it works. And returns a png plot on the desktop.

Comment: Set the permissions of the file to 755 (allow read/execute for all) see if that fixes it, if so then it's a permissions problem.

Comment: Sorry but I am completely new in these things. You mean to change the permissions of the R file? I did this: chmod u=rx  my_rscript.R
But when I want to do the same for the php file I get this error:chmod: "Unable to change file mode on test.php: Operation not permitted"

Comment: You did not tell us if "from PHP" means "from Apache/PHP" or similar. When used from a Web site, this most likely is security issue of the server; I would not dare to give you recommendations in that context for fear of opening security holes. If possible and no immediate feedback required, it could be most secure if you run R time- or event controlled in a separate job with different privileges.

Comment: @cryptic: Still doesn't work!

Comment: @Dieter: I use a local server (with MAMP) in order to test it.

Comment: What does the file do? If it is accessing files and directories those file/directories need to have the proper permissions as well. The file will be run as the server and as such all file/directories the script accesses need to allow access for the server.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But this R file doesn't access any directories. It just makes a simple plot and outputs it in the desktop..(png("temp.png")
plot(5,5)
dev.off()
)

Comment: The "desktop" IS a directory, it's not a place in cloud heaven where everyone can dump his waste.

Comment: Well I know it's a directory. But I just save the output there. I don't use any files which are there..

Comment: By the way, when I run the: exec("R CMD BATCH my_rscript.R"); command, I get as an output a myscript.Rout file..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this works for images, but I got nothing back until I stored the results in the second parameter of the exec() function

```
exec("Rscript test.R $N", $results);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Nice, this is the first time I got anything to show in the web browser from an rscript output.  Sadly does not work for the OPs (and my) issue with saving the image to a directory and displaying it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get the image saved to directory and visible on the web page.  From the command line:

```
chown www-data:www-data /usr/bin/Rscript
chown www-data:www-data -R /PATH/TO/RSCRIPTFOLDER
```

Changed permissions first on the Rscript executable, and then did the same for the entire folder that houses the .php file, .R file, etc.